# Not able to change the background color and access properties of array returned in fetch request

Tags: python-requests, fetch, response

I'm not able to access key value pairs of the return array object. I'm trying to pass the input value of my color selector and scheme selector to the API fetch call, but then I am unable to use those returned values to update the background of the div in the DOM.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
>! blank array let colorsArray = [] 






document.getElementById("get-color").addEventListener("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  const colorChoice = document.getElementById("color-value").value
  const schemeChoice = document.getElementById("schemes").value
  const schemesContainer = document.getElementById("color-schemes")
 
   data = {
       color: colorChoice,
       mode: schemeChoice``
          
   }  

       fetch(`https://www.thecolorapi.com/scheme?hex="${colorChoice}"&mode=${schemeChoice}&count=5`)
.then(response=> response.json())
.then(data=>{
  colorsArray.push(data.colors)

  
   
  
    const displayColors = colorsArray.forEach(function(colors, index){
        
      
        return `<div class="schemes" "style":backgroundColor= ${colors.hex.value}`
       
        
        
        
    })

    
})

})
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, please use more labels according to your programming language (JavaScript) and the framework if any. It could be also mentioned at the beginning of your post and/or in the title. Please also try to format your code for an easier readability.